# How to use class functions for handling interrupts?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, stm32

I've been trying to switch my code from Arduino to the ST HAL library. In Arduino I was using the attachInterrupt functions to handle button presses. I've replaced this by setting up interrupt using cubeMX, this results in the following function:

```
 void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
 {
 /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI15_10_IRQn 0 */
 if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_FLAG(BATTERY_BUTTON_Pin)){
   batteryButton.checkChange();
 }else if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_FLAG(CENTER_BUTTON_Pin)){
   centerButton.checkChange();
 }else if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_FLAG(MINUS_BUTTON_Pin)){
   minusButton.checkChange();
 }else if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_FLAG(PLUS_BUTTON_Pin)){
   plusButton.checkChange();
 }
```

As you can see I'm trying to call class functions for different buttons when pressed. I'm making these functions in my main (that I converted to a .cpp file) but this file (stm32f1xx_it) is a c file and has if statements to implement everything in c when the file is cpp. I've tried to include the button file here, but this gives errors since you cannot use classes in c. Is there a way I can still use this functions as triggers?

Comment: You can add C-style functions to .cpp file like `void battery_check() { batteryButton.checkChange(); }` and call then from c-file.

Comment: Just make sure that these C-style functions are made `extern "C"`!

Comment: Side-note: I wouldn't convert the main file to cpp, as cube will not consider it when re-generating, instead it just creates a new C-file and you'd have to merge by hand. Instead, apply the same trick as for the `[...]_it.c` file.

Comment: Note that it is not, in general, sufficient to assign functions to have C linkage (`extern "C"`).  You certainly must declare them that way to call them from C++, but if indeed they are written in C then it is foolhardy to try to compile them with a C++ compiler.  The two are different languages, and although there is a common subset, it is entirely possible for code extending beyond that subset to be interpreted successfully, but differently by a C++ compiler than it would be by a C compiler.

Comment: Thanks! The C-style functions work for now. I was planning to convert as much to C when I was done implementing the rest of my code, so I hope the compiler will not be an issue

Comment: Please remember about contact bounce. Do not use EXTI for generic user buttons even you have capacitor. Use polling instead. For ex. Poll buttons in SysTick Handler and if button pressed for a several ticks, handle this event in your main program (outside of interrupt context)